# How to place two toastr on different positions

Tags: javascript, toastr

Hi everyone I am using toastr (CodeSeven/toastr) I am facing one issue I was trying to put two toastrs one on the `top right corner` and another on the `bottom middle` using `toastr.options`, both should need to pop up almost at same time. But due to async calling both either appears on the bottom middle or at the top right based on which api call completes first.
How to resolve this issue? I want both of the toastrs to appear on their respective positions !!

Comment: Did You solved this?

Comment: @deblocker I found out that due to async calling this is happening, and I couldn't find any solution to this.